# Could not configure Gradle project (Kotlin code)

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am a pretty fresh in Gradle. I'm trying to build up a project Kotlin code with Gradle.
I have spent some time to learn that by following these instructions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

And so far, I have not succeeded in it and got some errors.

My build.gradle is shown below:

```
group = "kotlin"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And I got the following error

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
....
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50.
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have an SSL connection problem. Maybe you need to set a proxy server for Gradle. Just create a file `gradle.properties` with `systemProp.https.proxyHost=yourServer` as content.

Comment: it looks like that. But I am buiding up maven projects at the same time and it is successful without any proxy-server

Comment: I've just created a sample project with your gradle file and it works fine. So it must have something to do with your environment configuration (network etc.). Tested with Gradle 4.8.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do that.